# PHP server that loads contents from another server based on request

Tags: php, web-services, security, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am new in php, can any one help me how to build a php server that requests another server based on request from another server e.g

suppose two servers are `A.com` and `B.com` 
now i want to request `http:www.A.com/xyz` it will load content(`http://www.B.com/rst`) from `B.com` and will return me `http://www.B.com/rst` content.

This just to hide resources of `B.com` to the user of `A.com`- **i want to deploy my code at** `A.com`

**N.B. You can suggest better free solution/technology. I have access to a server where i can host php platform technologies**

Comment: file_get_contents(). Have a look at the documentation. RTFM

Comment: at http://www.B.com/rst you must code rest API return data and from http:www.A.com/xyz use this API get content or at rst only page content may you only need curl or file_get_contents() function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download contents of the PHP generated page from another PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854302/download-contents-of-the-php-generated-page-from-another-php-script)

Answer (score 2):

If it's simple content at http://www.B.com/rst, just do so at A.com:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/xyz'){
    $content = file_get_contents('http://www.B.com/rst'); 
    // probably you want to modify $content here. 
    echo $content; 
}
```

Please note the links may not work after doing this, so you would need to check and modify $content.